# Joda DateTime Field on Play Framework 2.0's Anorm

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I've been learning Play Framework, and the recommended way to access a database is using the build in anorm component. Thing is, there's no good support for DateTime in anorm. It's still using `java.util.Date`.

Is there any way to use Joda DateTime or java.sql.Timestamp in anorm?

If there's no way to use Joda or java.sql, can we add a module for that?

Comment: @adis I think that's about JPA, and this is for anorm...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

*update*: Since play 2.3.7 this is now [natively supported](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/3563).

I am using the following piece of code to work with DateTime seamlessly with Anorm.

```
import org.joda.time._
import org.joda.time.format._
import anorm._

object AnormExtension {


val dateFormatGeneration: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSS");

implicit def rowToDateTime: Column[DateTime] = Column.nonNull { (value, meta) =>
    val MetaDataItem(qualified, nullable, clazz) = meta
    value match {
        case ts: java.sql.Timestamp => Right(new DateTime(ts.getTime))
        case d: java.sql.Date => Right(new DateTime(d.getTime))
        case str: java.lang.String => Right(dateFormatGeneration.parseDateTime(str))  
        case _ => Left(TypeDoesNotMatch("Cannot convert " + value + ":" + value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass) )
    }
}

implicit val dateTimeToStatement = new ToStatement[DateTime] {
    def set(s: java.sql.PreparedStatement, index: Int, aValue: DateTime): Unit = {
        s.setTimestamp(index, new java.sql.Timestamp(aValue.withMillisOfSecond(0).getMillis()) )
    }
}

}
```

I think it should definitively be part of Anorm, just need to be polished and more tested.
Let me know if it has helped you.

Comment: You just put the code somewhere (e.g. to some utility package) and import it where you handle SQL statements and results by `import AnormExtension._`. Since the functions are defined to be `implicit`, Anorm will use them automatically for conversion once they are in scope.

Comment: Any chance you could explain this please? I'm not even sure why the problem occurs, and why this solves it? Thanks!

Comment: Reading the database is easy: 

`DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
          SQL(s"select $fieldName from $tableName where ${tableName}.id = " + """{id}""").on("id" -> id).as(scalar[DateTime].singleOpt).getOrElse(new DateTime(0l))
        }'

But how does on do so with a given `DateTimeZone`?

Comment: Ah -- `.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC)` which will do it's best to simply pass the original value IF the JVM is already on UTC time. (Which if you do maintenance from "other" machines that use a common/shared library could be a wildcard so better to have this explicitly set)