# Can't read Integer column using Anorm

Tags: scala, anorm

When I try to run (from Play Framework):

```
import play.api.db.DB
import anorm._
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import AnormExtensions._ // http://stackoverflow.com/a/11975107/11236
import play.api.Play.current
import java.util.Date

var stream = SQL("SELECT amiId, created, version FROM Amis WHERE created = {maxCreated}")
    .on("maxCreated" -> new Date(maxCreated.getMillis))
    .apply()

val map: Stream[Ami] = stream.map { ami =>
    val s: String = ami[String]("amiId")
    val date: Date = ami[Date]("created")

    // The following line throws a compilation error
    var version: Integer = ami[Integer]("version")

    new Ami(s, new DateTime(date), version)
}
```

I get a compilation error : `could not find implicit value for parameter c: anorm.Column[Integer]`

What's the problem here? If I can read a `Date`, why can't I read an `Integer`?

Comment: did you try instead of DateTime to use Date?

Comment: @Iraklis - actually `DateTime` is working just fine. The code above works well when I replace `ami[Integer]("version")` with `42`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I used java `java.lang.Integer` instead of `scala.Int`.

Answer (score 0):

Such missing numeric conversion was fixed with release of Play 2.3. You may want upgrade to.