# Joda time issue with MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, time, jodatime

I'm using the Play Framework 2.1.2, the JDBC MySQL Connector and Scala 2.10. The following query is my problem:

```scala
DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
  SQL("""SELECT SUM(r.dayFrequency) 
         FROM relationships AS r
         WHERE r.id = {id}
         AND
         (r.date BETWEEN {from} AND {to})""").on(
    'id -> id,
    'from -> from,
    'to -> to).as(scalar[Int](bigDecimalToInt).single)
}
```

It raises this exception:

```
Execution exception[[RuntimeException:     UnexpectedNullableFound(ColumnName(.SUM(r.dayFrequency),Some(SUM(r.dayFrequency))))]]
```

The console logs the following query:

```
 SELECT SUM(r.dayFrequency)              
 FROM relationships AS r              
 WHERE r.id = 26180              
 AND              
(r.date BETWEEN 2014-08-04 12:00:00.0 AND 2014-08-04 12:00:00.0)
```

If I run this query on my MySQL Workbench it returns null, which confirms the exception. But with this change in the query it works:

```sql
(r.date BETWEEN '2014-08-04' AND '2014-08-04')
```

For the conversion of Joda `DateTime`, I use this piece of code: [Joda DateTime Field on Play Framework 2.0's Anorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388301/joda-datetime-field-on-play-framework-2-0s-anorm)

and frequency and date field looks like the following:

```sql
date DATE NOT NULL,
dayFrequency INT
```

Can anyone help with this problem? Seems that something is wrong with the conversion.

**EDIT** after first POST below:

From the view I receive date strings like this `2014-08-04` and I convert them into Joda DateTime in my controller to compare them to other and use them in MySQL queries like this:

```scala
private def clientDateStringToTimestamp(date: String) = {
    val Array(year, month, day) = date.split("-")
    new DateTime(year.toInt, month.toInt, day.toInt, 12, 0, 0).getMillis()
}
new DateTime(clientDateStringToTimestamp("2014-08-04"))
```

For the MySQL queries I want to compare only the date part not the time part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i did a simple experiment in mysql:

```
mysql> create table t (v int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into t values (null);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select sum(v) from t;
+--------+
| sum(v) |
+--------+
|   NULL |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into t values (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select sum(v) from t;
+--------+
| sum(v) |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update t set v = NULL;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select sum(v) from t;
+--------+
| sum(v) |
+--------+
|   NULL |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So this tells us that a summing nulls to nulls gives us null but summing nulls to numbers gives us numbers.

I suspect that your first query `(r.date BETWEEN 2014-08-04 12:00:00.0 AND 2014-08-04 12:00:00.0)` returns just rows with null dayFrequency values, where the second query `(r.date BETWEEN '2014-08-04' AND '2014-08-04')`, which is offset 12 hours earlier returns at least one non-null frequency. So since null is possible, you will have to use `scalar[Option[Int]]` for the sum, then turn it to 0 with `getOrElse`. A better way, if you can is to make the `dayFrequency` column in the database `NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`. Then it will give you a 0, and you can sum away

Comment: Note that `scalar[Option[Int]]` is buggy before version 2.3 . BTW version 2.1 'starts' to be quite old knowing Anorm release cycle.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation and I fully agree. But actually I want the query to be like the second one from my play application. There is a relationship entry with frequency 1 on 2014-08-04 in my Database. I only want to compare the date not the time part at all. So it looks like it is comparing the "2014-08-04 12:00:00.0" with the date from the database, which may be converted to something like "2014-08-04 XX:XX:XX.0". But I need to ensure, that they are equal ignoring the time part. My dates are stored as "year-month-day" in my database.

Comment: Ok, you got me on the right track. Changing the hours from 12 to zero in the timestamp creation (look at the edit in my original question) fixed it. So MySQL is converting the "2014-08-04" in the database to 2014-08-04 00:00:00.0. I also changed the defaults, thanks! Soon I will upgrade to the new play version, but the code base is very big and it will take some time.

Answer (score 0):

Also related, direct support for Joda temporal types in Anorm: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/commit/bdbbbe90822a6fb150c7044e68b33e2e52a7323d

Comment: Nice! Thank you. Can't wait for the next release.

Comment: You can run Play master from sources: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/BuildingFromSource