# Handle Joda DateTime with Anorm 2.3

Tags: scala, jodatime, playframework-2.3, anorm

I'm brand new to Play! and I'm using the version 2.3.4.

So far I used the `java.util.Date` type without problem but I finally want to use a `DateTime` type.

So I'm trying to use the `org.joda.time.DateTime` type but `anorm` doesn't know how to handle this type, I get this error : `could not find implicit value for parameter extractor: anorm.Column[org.joda.time.DateTime]`.

The part of the code giving an error is :

```
private val ArtistParser: RowParser[Artist] = {
    get[Long]("artistId") ~
    get[DateTime]("creationDateTime") map {
        case artistId ~ creationDateTime =>
        Artist(artistId, creationDateTime)
    }
}
```

My class is simply :

```
case class Artist (artistId: Long, creationDateTime: DateTime)
```

I have been searching a solution for a long time and I looked in particular at this post : 
[Joda DateTime Field on Play Framework 2.0's Anorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388301/joda-datetime-field-on-play-framework-2-0s-anorm) but I think that it doesn't work with play 2.3.4 (at least I didn't manage to make it work).

So my question is how do you handle `DateTime` with play scala 2.3? Is there an easiest way to proceed? And if not what should I do in order to `anorm` to handle correctly the `DateTime` type?

Comment: Did you `import AnormExtension._` (the linked solution) ? It works for me.

Comment: Yes I have imported it, but I get the error mentioned above. Do you use play 2.3?

Comment: Yes, it works in 2.3.x

Comment: I'm probably missing something, I import correctly AnormExtension and there is nothing more in my code that mentioned above. Do you maybe have a link in order to me to have a look at your code?

Answer (score 0):

Anorm typeclasses for Joda `DateTime` and `Instant` are present in play master. You may want to give it a try.